# Argument of type 'File' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'. React with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

How can I set the correct type in useState so I can push image as File in array ?

Here is my useState:

```
const [colorsAndImages, setColorsAndImages] = useState([{ images: [], colors: '' }])
```

Here is where I'm trying to push the image but I'm getting an error:

```
const handleSetImage = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>, index: number) => {
        const file = event.target.files;
        const list = [...colorsAndImages]
        list[index].images.push(file?.item(0)!)
        setColorsAndImages(list)
    };
```

The error is on ...(file?.item(0)!)

> Argument of type 'File' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'never'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the `useState` hook without an explicit generic, TypeScript will try to infer the type from the initial passed value.

Since your initial value includes an empty array (for `images`), TypeScript is unable to determine the type of the values that will be in that array and so assigns it the type `never`.

To fix this, explicitly specify the type of your state when you initialize it:

```
const [colorsAndImages, setColorsAndImages] = useState<{images: File[], colors: string}[]>([{ images: [], colors: '' }])
```

Comment: I did almost the same only without the last definition of array here `<{images: File[], colors: string}[]>`